# .telnetrc not being read at startup of telnet

Tags: ubuntu, telnet

I'm trying to set up some telnet commands in `~/.telnetrc`
and they are not being read. The file is

```
DEFAULT
  mode line
```

When I go into telnet and do a "display", I get ...

```
environ         change environment variables ('environ ?'
telnet> display
will flush output when sending interrupt characters.
won't send interrupt characters in urgent mode.
won't read the telnetrc files.
won't map carriage return on output.
will recognize certain control characters.
```

Transcribed from this image, which appears to be cropped:

[image: Transcribed from this image]

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Is something needed to tell telnet to read the `.telnetrc` file at startup?

Comment: The hostname or the keyword `DEFAULT` has to be on the same line as the options being set. Take a look at the telnetrc [man](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54775/telnetrc-4.html) page.

Comment: @doneal24 I'm not sure if that man page is wrong or is some Oracle-specific thing, but [the man page for `telnet` on Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/telnet-ssl.1.html) states: "Commands should be one per line, indented by whitespace..."

Comment: @jamesdlin  In reading the entire paragraph you're referencing, lines beginning with non-whitespace are interpreted as hostnames. So you have an option of just having a command executed or of restricting the command execution to only named hosts (or the DEFAULT host).

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216).  And especially don't embed images of text when the text is already in the question *as text*.